# jquery mutiple div with a single definition script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hide").click(function () {
        $("div1").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function () {
        $("div1").show();
    });
});
```

and this jsp/html

```
for{int=0;i<V_loopnumber;i++)
{
 %>
 <button id='show' height:10px>showit</button>

 <div1>
  something
 <button id='hide' height:10px>hideit</button>
 </div1>
 <%
}
```

For example if I have 3 elements, it produces 3 divs. However,if I push the button all the divs will be showed or hided cause they got the same name.
how can I differentiate the button with the respective divs?

Comment: Same IDs must not be shared by multiple elements. Consider fixing that first before solving bigger issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup has a few problems. You can not assign the same ID twice. Also `div1` is not a valid tag name.

Perhaps you can restructure your markup along the lines of the following example:

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="show">showit</button>
    <div class="inner">
        something
        <button class="hide">hideit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I assigned the buttons `class`es instead of `id`s and got rid of the `div1` elements.

Now you can listen for a click event on the buttons and hide the related elements using the `.closest()` (http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method like this:

```
$(".hide").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".inner").hide();
});
```

`$(this).closest(".inner")` will retrieve the the closest element with the class `inner` up in the dom tree.

```
$(".show").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".inner").show();
});
```

`$(this).parent().find(".inner")` will go up one level in the dom tree and find the element with the class `inner`.

**http://jsfiddle.net/KGk7B/**

Comment: thanks so much! really good documentation and example, but how can i hide the "showit" button when the <div> is showed yet?

Answer (score 1):

First, element `id`s must be unique. Use a class instead. Second, `<div1>` isn't a valid tag. Use a `div` with a class instead. Third, use traversal functions to find the specific element to toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hide").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.show-hide-container').hide();
    });
    $(".show").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.show-hide-container').show();
    });
});
```

---

```
for{int=0;i<V_loopnumber;i++)
{
 %>
 <button class='show' height:10px>showit</button>

 <div class="show-hide-container">
  something
 <button class='hide' height:10px>hideit</button>
 </div>
 <%
}
```

Comment: how `closest` can work, above `show` button there can be `hide` button, because buttons are generating in loop. will `closest` check in bottom only?

Comment: @RajivRanjan I'm only using `.closest()` on the `.hide` button, and targeting a direct parent of the button.

Answer (score 1):

id must be **unique** on your page, use *class*

```
<button class='show' height:10px>showit</button>
```

and use **$(this)** in event callback function instead of using selector

```
$(".hide").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide(); // this is hard select of your div1, i wrote only for your html
 });
```

> **IMPORTANT:** Use div instead of div1, div1 tag is undefined.